# Adding UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton in a tableview - beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` on some cells in a `UITableView`, and when i scroll the table, the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` gets appeared on cells that were not suppose to display the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` button. Can someone tell me why this is happening and how i could prevent it.

I have entered the code to add the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` in the following code:

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the table views delegate try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Replace with your Row/cell check...
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does `% 2` do ? Sorry i am a beginner

Comment: That would make it so every other cell switches the accessoryType; its a mod operator.  Replace that line with your own if statement code though :).

Comment: @chown isn´t it spelled modulo?

Comment: @wag Yes, it is technically called a "modulo operation".  The more common usage though is saying "5 mod 4" (and "5 modulo 4" just sounds silly).  As a programmer, I do enough typing so when an abbreviated expression exists, I am inclined to use it ).